# Why the proposal site is not showing updated status about Law SE's Private Beta?

Tags: bug

When Law SE released it's Private Beta a new [tab](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/67858?phase=beta) showed up in it's proposal site. Strangely (as of now) it is showing only 0% in every item! It shows, for instance, 0 questions per day, 0 users with 200+ reputation, among other false zeros.

My question is, why are those percents not being updated, since they are very valuable to keep track of the success of Law SE?

**UPDATE:** Now (1st July, 21:30 GMT) the percents are now being calculated! Anyway, the question still remains, what caused it to be 6 days without any update?

Comment: Blame it on caching. It happens on every beta site for the first few days.

Comment: @HDE226868, Well, lets give it a few more days and see if it stops happening. Anyway, it is a bug, right?

Comment: I've never seen it this bad on  any other site in which I participated in private beta.

Comment: Probably someone forgot to flip the on/off switch?

Comment: I second @TomAu; this is a bit much.

Comment: Is it *supposed* to show private beta stats?

Comment: @cpast Perhaps not. Couldn't find an authoritative answer whether it works only for public or private betas.

Comment: It seems like it should (by my recollection). I pinged the devs to check in on it.